# Sending data from the tableview via swip To Another view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a button in the tableviewCell

in  swift UIKit

It sends the data to another viewer

This is it

```
@IBAction func EditTable(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if let qusID = QRModelContent?.id {
        tapQVC?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetailsEdite", sender: qusID)
    }
}
```

And through Table View

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDetailsEdite" {
        let destintion = segue.destination as? EditeView
        destintion?.detailsBtnTable = sender as! String
}
}
```

Here it works great

But I want to transfer via swip TableView

I tried here but it gives me an error

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    
    let edite = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (action, view, nil) in

        if let qusID = self.QRModelContent?.id {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetailsEdite", sender: qusID)
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is an example video

[enter link description here](https://i.top4top.io/m_20414dhi31.mov)

Comment: It gives you *what* error?

Comment: I mean in writing the code there is an error

Comment: When I press the button, nothing works

Comment: You're not returning anything from `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`. In fact, the compiler is probably giving you a warning that `edite` is unused.

Comment: What does "Sending data from the tableview via swip To Another view"?  There is no English word spelled as 'swip.'

Comment: What is a guy named 'EditeView'?  What is its relationship with a guy named 'Table View'?

Comment: I sent an edit follow the video

Comment: EditeView is class To whom will the data be sent?